# How to get card specs programmatically in CUDA

Tags: cuda, nvidia, specs

I'm just starting out with CUDA. Is there a way of getting the card specs programmatically?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the [cudaGetDeviceCount](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g18808e54893cfcaafefeab31a73cc55f) and [cudaGetDeviceProperties](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g1bf9d625a931d657e08db2b4391170f0) APIs.

```
void DisplayHeader()
{
    const int kb = 1024;
    const int mb = kb * kb;
    wcout << "NBody.GPU" << endl << "=========" << endl << endl;

    wcout << "CUDA version:   v" << CUDART_VERSION << endl;    
    wcout << "Thrust version: v" << THRUST_MAJOR_VERSION << "." << THRUST_MINOR_VERSION << endl << endl; 

    int devCount;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&devCount);
    wcout << "CUDA Devices: " << endl << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < devCount; ++i)
    {
        cudaDeviceProp props;
        cudaGetDeviceProperties(&props, i);
        wcout << i << ": " << props.name << ": " << props.major << "." << props.minor << endl;
        wcout << "  Global memory:   " << props.totalGlobalMem / mb << "mb" << endl;
        wcout << "  Shared memory:   " << props.sharedMemPerBlock / kb << "kb" << endl;
        wcout << "  Constant memory: " << props.totalConstMem / kb << "kb" << endl;
        wcout << "  Block registers: " << props.regsPerBlock << endl << endl;

        wcout << "  Warp size:         " << props.warpSize << endl;
        wcout << "  Threads per block: " << props.maxThreadsPerBlock << endl;
        wcout << "  Max block dimensions: [ " << props.maxThreadsDim[0] << ", " << props.maxThreadsDim[1]  << ", " << props.maxThreadsDim[2] << " ]" << endl;
        wcout << "  Max grid dimensions:  [ " << props.maxGridSize[0] << ", " << props.maxGridSize[1]  << ", " << props.maxGridSize[2] << " ]" << endl;
        wcout << endl;
    }
}
```

If you have installed the **GPU Computing SDK**, have a look at the `deviceQuery` project which can be found in the `%NVSDKCOMPUTE_ROOT%\C\src` directory. It shows how to query for all the device properties using CUDA Runtime API calls.

The [CUDA Programming guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) has more detail in section 3.2.3.

### Update:

The `deviceQuery` sample is not packaged with the CUDA Toolkit anymore, you can find it on [GitHub](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery) instead.