# How to enable/disable a specific graphic card?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I'm working on a "fujitsu" machine. It has 2 GPUs installed: Quadro 2000 and Tesla C2075. The Quadro GPU has 1 GB RAM and Tesla GPU has 5GB of it. (I checked using the output of nvidia-smi -q). When I run nvidia-smi, the output shows 2 GPUs, but the Tesla ones display is shown as off. 
I'm running a memory intensive program and would like to use 5 GB of RAM available, but whenever I run a program, it seems to be using the Quadro GPU.
Is there some way to use a particular GPU out of the 2 in a program? Does the Tesla GPU being "disabled" means it's drivers are not installed?

Comment: Are you trying to trigger this programmatically from your own application? Or is this a general question about the machine?

Comment: @DanHarris It's a general question. I just want to know how do I use the 5GB GPU installed on my machine?

Comment: I would say this question would be better on http://superuser.com/ as Stack Overflow is for programming questions. SuperUser is better suited to asking questions such as this.

Comment: This question is fine here. The answer to this question is useful to CUDA programmers.

Comment: In general you can use `cudaSetDevice`. It will need a number, which is the GPU ID you want to run the computations on. Which number refers to which card can be determined according to the accepted answer to this post [How to get card specs programatically in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689028/how-to-get-card-specs-programatically-in-cuda). Could you please clarify what do you mean by _but the Tesla ones display is shown as off_?

Answer (score 9):

You can control access to CUDA GPUs either using the environment or programmatically.

You can use the environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to specify a list of 1 or more GPUs that will be visible to any application, as well as their order of visibility. For example if nvidia-smi reports your Tesla GPU as GPU 1 (and your Quadro as GPU 0), then you can  set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1` to enable only the Tesla to be used by CUDA code.

See my [blog post on the subject](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/).

To control what GPU your application uses programmatically, you should use the [device management API of CUDA](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE). Query the number of devices using `cudaGetDeviceCount`, then you can `cudaSetDevice` to each device, query its properties using `cudaGetDeviceProperties`, and then select the device that fits your application criteria.  You can also use [`cudaChooseDevice`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g028e5b0474379eaf5f5d54657d48600b) to select the device that most closely matches the device properties you specify.